# Move point to next tab-stop in Emacs

Tags: emacs, tabs, elisp

I am trying to create a major mode in Emacs. In this mode the tab key should work as follows:

- I define a number, e.g. `(setq my-tab-stop 10)`
- When I hit the tab key the point moves to next column that is divisible by `my-tab-stop`, i.e.
- If `current-column` is equal to 0,1,2,..,9, the point should move to column 10,
- If `current-column` is equal to 10,11,12,..,19, the point should move to column 20, and so on..

(Note: no spaces or tabs should be inserted (like in `tab-to-tab-stop`), only the point moves, however, if the point moves beyond the length of the current line, spaces should be inserted to make line longer)

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the code:

```
(defvar tabtab-val 10)

(defun tabtab/forward-char (n)
  (let ((space (- (line-end-position) (point))))
    (if (> space tabtab-val)
        (forward-char n)
      (move-end-of-line 1)
      (insert (make-string (- n space) ? )))))

(defun tabtab ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((shift (mod (current-column) tabtab-val)))
    (tabtab/forward-char (- tabtab-val shift))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just bind a key to `move-to-tab-stop`.

You can trivially configure the tab stop list for fixed intervals of N columns with:

```
(setq tab-stop-list (number-sequence N MAX N))
```